# Move from regular variable group to a linked to key vault in azure devops yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-keyvault, azure-pipelines-yaml

I use variable group to store my contextual variables.
I decided to move those to a key vault as i need to use them from elsewhere

I used the same variable name (to avoid any rewrite in my pipelines) and just changed the variable group name

```
#- group: VariablesPipeline
- group: technical-kv
# 'azdo-serviceconnection-name' variable in each group
```

In those group, i've a variable that store the service connection name (type Az Resource Manager) that i use on many tasks (mostly AzurePowershell tasks) which are stored in yaml templates

```
        - task: AzurePowerShell@5
          displayName: Compute things
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: '$(azdo-serviceconnection-name)'
            ScriptType: 'FilePath'
            ScriptPath: my script path           
            FailOnStandardError: true
            azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

But i have error that says that nothing is provided as serviceconnection name

```
[...]
##[debug]loading SECRET_AZDO-SERVICECONNECTION-NAME
[...]
##[debug]loaded 41
[...]

##[debug]FailOnStandardError=true
##[debug]TargetAzurePs=LatestVersion
##[debug]CustomTargetAzurePs=undefined
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Input required: ConnectedServiceNameARM
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Input required: ConnectedServiceNameARM
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Input required: ConnectedServiceNameARM
```

I expected my variable, that was previously working this way with a regular variable group, to be interpreted to make my pipeline work.

Did i miss something ?
Is there limitations on where i can use those variables from key vaults ?

Comment: Do you really need to store service connection name i KeyVault? This is not secret and can only be used on AzureDevops? What is the purpose of this?

Comment: The idea was to move everything which is in a variable group to a key vault. But indeed, this may need a split to keep those specific info in a regular variable group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests, i conclude that this kind of parameter can't be get on time to be used as service connection name

My solution is to let this specific azdo information in a regular variable group

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).